# Hibernate JPA Filter by Subclass Properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following JPA entities,

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class OrderItem {

    // some inherited fields

}
```

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPE1")
public class OrderItemTypeOne extends OrderItem {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orderItem")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private SomeTypeA a;

}
```

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPE2")
public class OrderItemTypeTwo extends OrderItem {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orderItem")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private SomeTypeB b;

}
```

I want to perform a query that gives me all OrderItems where a = 'a' (for OrderItemTypeOne) and b = 'b' (for OrderItemTypeTwo) in one JPA query. How can I achieve this? So far I have this query, but it gives a SQLGrammarException at runtime.

```
@Query("SELECT oi FROM OrderItem oi "
            + "LEFT JOIN OrderItemTypeOne t1 "
            + "LEFT JOIN OrderItemTypeTwo t2 "
            + "WHERE t1.a = :a "
            + "AND t2.b = :b")
Page<OrderItem> findOrders(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
```

I've tried using this approach,

```
@Query("SELECT oi FROM OrderItem oi "
            + "WHERE treat(oi as OrderItemTypeOne).a = :a "
            + "AND treat(oi as OrderItemTypeTwo).b = :b")
Page<OrderItem> findOrders(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
```

but this does not work since treat() only works if I give a child property, e.g., `treat(oi.someOtherProperty as SomeOtherType)`.

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should use `or`-clause instead of `and` here

```
 select oi 
 from OrderItem oi 
 where treat(oi as OrderItemTypeOne).a=:a or treat(oi as OrderItemTypeTwo).b=:b
```

When you use `and`-clause you get nothing because `OrderItem` cannot be an instance of `OrderItemTypeOne` and `OrderItemTypeTwo` at the same time.

Another approach is to use cross-join this way

```
select oi 
from OrderItem oi, OrderItemTypeOne t1, OrderItemTypeTwo t2
where (oi.id=t1.id or oi.id=t2.id) and (t1.a=:a or t2.b=:b)
```

where `oi.id` - `OrderItem` id field name

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
@Query("SELECT oi FROM OrderItem oi "
            + "WHERE oi.a = :a "
            + "OR oi.b = :b")
Page<OrderItem> findOrders(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
```